# Second press of a GUI button

Tags: java, user-interface, button, uibutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to allow my button to be pressed a second time in my GUI after calculating and displaying dice rolled by a user. So far the only solution I've come up with is putting a .setSource(false); statement in my actionListener for my button. Where do I place my code (and I'm assuming there may be a more efficient statement to reset my button)?

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == button){
            /* my output when button is pressed
            .
            .
            . */
            e.setSource(false);
          }
    });
```

Comment: You want to reset your button GUI as in you need the button to change the text display within the button every time you clicked the button?

Comment: Why would you want to ***reset*** it?

Comment: @user3437460 post edited. I'm hoping to allow a second button press in my program which will replace the corresponding ouput after the button is clicked.

Comment: @DevilsHnd ^ answer in comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps utilize a class global boolean variable to be used as a toggle flag:

```
public class MyClass {

    boolean toggle = false;
    /*
      other relative class code
    */


    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // If button is selected the first time.
        if (e.getSource() == button && !toggle){
            toggle = true;
            /* my output when button is pressed the first time.
            .
            .
            . */

            e.setSource(false);
        }
        // If button is selected the second time.
        if (e.getSource() == button && toggle){
            toggle = false;
            /* my output when button is pressed the second time.
            .
            .
            . */
            e.setSource(false);
        }
    });
```